# meteor update - collection not updating even though it reports it does

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to update a collection but I for some reason, even though it traces as having succeeded, when I view that collection in my console it doesn't appear to have updated.

Here's what I'm doing:

1) calling the update function from a javascript function on the client. All the values are being passed correctly:

```
Meteor.call('minisiteUpdater',vLayout,vColour,vBG,vHFont,vBFont,vFontColour);
```

2) the function itself (defined in Meteor.methods) is as follows. Note that when I log everything in the console, all the values are passed successfully into the function and the siteID I get from the session var is also correctly set. The problem is that the console is logging "success", which suggests to me that the update has worked, but when I enter Therapistminisite.find().fetch() into the console afterwards and look at the supposedly updated collection item, it has not been updated.

```
minisiteUpdater: function(vLayout,vColour,vBG,vHFont,vBFont,vFontColour){
    var updates = { $set: { 
        layout: vLayout,
        colour: vColour,
        backgroundimage: vBG,
        headingfont: vHFont,
        bodyfont: vBFont,
        fontcolour: vFontColour
    }};

    var siteID = Session.get("currentSiteBuilderID");

    Therapistminisite.update(siteID, updates, function (error) {
        if (error){
            console.log(error);
        }
        else{
            console.log("success");
        }
    });
},
```

Finally, just after I get the "success" logged in the console, I also get the following error message: "Error invoking Method 'minisiteUpdater': Internal server error [500]".

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you see 'success' on your browser console or your command line console?

Comment: I think you can only call Session.get on the client.  You might be seeing the success message when it runs the method on the client, but then a failure message from the server.

It then sends the unmodified record back to the client, and overwrites the local change you have made before you can check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that is the method definition for both the server and the client,
you can't call Session.get on the server side, so that method succeeds when called in the browser, but then fails when called on the server.  If you look in your server console, you should see a server error: `Session is not defined` corresponding to the 500 error in the browser console.

try adding the siteId as a method param, and removing the line that gets it from the session:

```
minisiteUpdater: function(vLayout,vColour,vBG,vHFont,vBFont,vFontColour, siteID){
  var updates = { $set: { 
    layout: vLayout,
    colour: vColour,
    backgroundimage: vBG,
    headingfont: vHFont,
    bodyfont: vBFont,
    fontcolour: vFontColour
  }};

  Therapistminisite.update(siteID, updates, function (error) {
    if (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
    else{
        console.log("success");
    }
  });
},
```

(remove this line: `var siteID = Session.get("currentSiteBuilderID");`)

and then pass in `Session.get("currentSiteBuilderID")` when you call it from the client like this:

```
Meteor.call(
  'minisiteUpdater',
  vLayout,
  vColour,
  vBG,
  vHFont,
  vBFont,
  vFontColour,
  Session.get("currentSiteBuilderID")
);
```